# Python Tkinter f string to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

How to put end-users email content to an f-string in Python? What should we insert here `st.insert(INSERT, "...")`, so that mail.Body # (1) gets s`t` variable and works like mail.Body # (2)? I'm sorry if I don't explain my question clearly. This is my first question in Python.

```
st = ScrolledText(window)
st.insert(INSERT, "...")
st.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=20, ipadx=50)

def SendEmail():
    # Load email info into dataframe
    try:
        email_info = pd.read_excel(email_file_path)
        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        for index, row in email_info.iterrows():
            mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
            mail.To = row["Email"]
            mail.CC = row["CC"]
            mail.Subject = f"OOReport for: {row['Vendor']}"
            mail.Body = st.get(1.0, END)  # (1)
            mail.Body = f"""Hi {row['First Name']}  # (2)

            Please find the attached report for {row['Vendor']}.

            Thanks,
            xxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxx
            yuyyyyyyy
            zzzzzz

            """
     
    except Exception as e:
         messagebox.showerror('Python Error', e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.

```
st.insert(INSERT, """f\"""Hi {row['First Name']}

Please find the attached report for {row['Vendor']}.

Best regards,
xxxxxxx
yuyyyyyyy
zzzzzz
\"""
        
""")

mail.Body = eval(st.get(1.0, END))
```